# How can I implement the scrolling found in Transit on the App Store?

Tags: swift, interface-builder

I'd like to implement a way to scroll content similar to [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/transit-app-real-time-bus/id498151501?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4) iOS app in the App Store, but I'm not even sure how this type of scrolling is called. Specifically, I'd like to be able to have a view that I can drag over another view, like how you can drag the list of transit options over the map view. Would I need to start off with using a UIScrollView to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you referring to how part of the scrolled section scrolls at a different speed from the others? i.e. the green bar at the bottom, when you drag it up, the map moves slower than it? Thats called "Parallax Scrolling"

Comment: Instead of making your question depend on a link to an app in the app store, update your question so it stands on its own. Describe exactly what you are trying to do and what issue you are having.